# Generalized measures

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

This question is kind of broad. I welcome any answer, but I'll be more than happy to look it up myself in some book, if you could mention some title.

Here's the setting: there's a Lie group $G$ acting via endomorphisms on an algebra $A$ with the action $\rho$, and there's its Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ acting via derivations with the action $\gamma$. We require the two actions to be compatible by the equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}(\rho(\exp(t\xi))(a))=(\gamma(\xi)(a))\ \forall a\in A,\xi\in\mathfrak g
\end{equation}
The problem is: how to define this derivative in general? The book I'm studying on ("Supersymmetry and equivariant de Rham Theory", by Guillemin and Sternberg) claims this is possible if $A$ is equipped with "some kind of topology" or if any $a\in A$ is $G-$finite (i.e. the orbits of the $G-$action are all finite).
I don't see how one should do this: I can accept, in principle, that giving a topology one can define limits, but I don't see clearly how the argumentation goes.
As for $G-$finiteness, I understand that the fact that $\rho(g)(a)$ can only be a finite number of elements forces the limit we want to define to converge somewhere - but again: does it? And this is only an idea, I can't formalize anything.

The second point is analogous. Pick the Lie group to be compact, consider an Haar measure $\mu$. We want to make sense of the assignment
\begin{equation}
A\ni a\mapsto \int_G\rho(g)(a)d\mu(g)\in A
\end{equation}
hence we need to be able to define the integral. The claim of the author is again that this is possible in the cases mentioned above - but they still don't mention how, and I keep not seeing it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big question, small answer. I leave it here, in case some other wanderer has the same doubt: the group/algebra structure is really not relevant for the problem. The point is that everything happen in vector spaces.

Now, there are two things that may be happening:

1. The setting is finite dimensional. This means that the orbit spaces are finite dimensional, as well as the space where $a$ lives - maybe the algebra is graded, and every grade is finite dimensional. Then everything boils down to a function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$, and the notions of derivative and integral are clear. For the integral you probably need $n=1$... but then again, it's nothing so exotic;
2. There is something infinite dimensional going on. Here you want to be able to define limits, and the idea is to require that the algebra is somehow normed. A family of seminorms is enough, and this is the kind of problem one deals with when working in superanalysis. There's a book by Quillen about it.